# How to format default dates for apiary blueprint?

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

Currently I'm trying to fix the following 2 warnings with the the following format.

```
+ start: `2015-05-05T12:30:00` - (optional, datetime) The start datetime (ISO8601 format) 
    + Default: `0001-01-01-T12:00:00+00:00`
+ end: `2015-05-06T15:20:12` - (optional, datetime) The end datetime (ISO8601 format)
    + Default: `Utc Now`
```

My warning are:

`Specifying parameter 'start' as required supersedes its default value, declare the parameter as 'optional' to specify its default value.`

`Specifying parameter 'end' as required supersedes its default value, declare the parameter as 'optional' to specify its default value.`

Answer (score 0):

Found the 2 mistakes the type was specified after the `-` and `datetime` is not a valid type.

correct format

```
+ start: `2015-05-05T12:30:00` (optional, string) - The start datetime (ISO8601 format) 
    + Default: `0001-01-01-T12:00:00+00:00`
+ end: `2015-05-06T15:20:12` (optional, datetime) - The end datetime (ISO8601 format)
    + Default: `Utc Now`
```